# Merging databases - adding rows that not existing in one db to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 databases from Wordpress website.
There was happenned issue and 50% of my posts dissapeared.

I have database 1 copy from 03.03.21
And existing database 2 of website from 24.03.21

So in database 1 i have many posts thats was deleted
And the database 2 has some new posts that not exist in older database 1

Is there any software or a way to merge these 2 database.
To compare databases and add entries to the newer database that are in the older database?

I could do this manullay but one post has entries in a many tables and its gonna be hard to recover deleted posts

Comment: There is no magic bullet if thats what you are hoping for

Comment: Without a LOT OF CARE doing it at all will very soon get you in a royal and horrible mess.

Comment: Some hosting companies do backups for you, have you checked there is not a backup you could restore that would loos you less than either of these databases you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy solution but you could try to make a *"merge"* locally for testing purposes.
Here's how I would do it, I can't guarrantee it will work.

**1.** Load the oldest backup into the server, let's say in a database named `merge_target`.

**2.** Load the 2nd backup (the most recent one) into the same server, let's say in a `merge_source` database.

**3.** Define a logical order to execute the merge for each table, this depends on the presence of foreign keys:

> If a table `A` has a foreign key referencing table `B`, then you will need to merge table  `B` before table `A`.

This may not work depending on your database structure (and I never worked with WordPress myself).

**4.** Write and execute queries for each table, with some rules:

- `SELECT` from the `merge_source` database
- `INSERT` into the `merge_target` database
- if a row already exists in `merge_target` (i.e. they have the same primary key or unique key), you can use MySQL features depending on what you want to do:

  - `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if the existing row should be updated
  - `INSERT IGNORE` if the row should just be skipped
  - `REPLACE` if you really need to delete and re-insert the row

This could look like the following query (here with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`):

```sql
INSERT INTO merge_target (col_a, col_b, col_c)
SELECT
    col_a
    , col_b
    , col_c
FROM merge_source
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    merge_target.col_b = merge_source.col_b
```

Documentation:

- [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)
- [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
- [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)
- [`INSERT IGNORE` is in the `INSERT` documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

---

> Not sure it will help but I wrote a database migration framework in PHP, you can still take a look: [Fregata](https://github.com/AymDev/Fregata).